# How to properly clear buffer for input (First Project) #rewritten code

Tags: c

How do i proplerly clear input buffer since fflush(stdin) is undefined and only available in some compilers,

My plan is to clear input since after looping back it still use the buffered input rather than getting a new input.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//bool function
bool isInteger(double val)
{
    int truncated = (int)val;
    return (val == truncated);
}

int main()
{
    //local variable
    double result, a, b;
    char oper, option = 'y';
    
    //loop
    while(option == 'y')
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Enter number and operator to solve:\n\nExapmple [a + b][a - b][a * b][a / b]\n");
        scanf("%lf %c %lf", &a, &oper, &b);
        
        // nested if
        if(isInteger(a) && isInteger(b))
        {
            if(oper == '+')
            {
                result = a + b; //calculation
                printf("%.1lf %c %.1lf = %.1lf\n\n", a, oper, b, result); //ouput result
            }
            else if(oper == '-')
            {
                result = a - b; //calculation
                printf("%.1lf %c %.1lf = %.1lf\n\n", a, oper, b, result); //ouput result
            }
            else if(oper == '*')
            {
                result = a * b; //calculation
                printf("%.1lf %c %.1lf = %.1lf\n\n", a, oper, b, result); //ouput result
            }
            else if(oper == '/')
            {
                result = a / b; //calculation
                printf("%.1lf %c %.1lf = %.1lf\n\n", a, oper, b, result); //ouput result
            }
            else
            {
                //output error
                printf("Invalid Operater!\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //output error
            printf("Input is not a digit!\n");
        }
        //output selection
        printf("Do you want to retry y/n?");
        option = getch();
    } // end loop
}
```

I only use scanf since we are still in scanf and printf.

Please help me out, this is our first project in college.

Comment: Try to replace `option = getch()` with `scanf(" %c", &option)` (note the blank between `"` and `%`)

Comment: Be aware that `scanf` is impractical interactive input. For robust interactve input you need to use `fgets` and parse the input yourself. But for simple school projects `scanf` is probably OK.

Comment: sorry i didnt elaborate, @jabberwocky

my problem is for example : 

i input 1 + 1 and get result but after looping back and ask for input, i input a + 1 but i get the same result from first input rather than giving error "input is not digit"

`scanf("%lf %c %lf", &a, &oper, &b);`

thats what i want to clear.

Comment: but i think that the problem lies in my input validator since operation validate is working

Comment: but i dont know anyway to validate if input is number or letter since it was not discussed by our teacher and i wont use things that was not in our discussion as it will raise question form our teacher

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to completely clear stdin and the \n before scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772103/how-to-completely-clear-stdin-and-the-n-before-scanf)