# How do I get new input after a failed `scanf()`?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm designing a function `get_num()` that takes as an argument an integer that represents a minimum value. The
function is supposed to repeatedly ask the user to enter a number until the user enters an integer greater than or equal
to the given minimum. The function should return the valid entry as an integer.

The function may assume the user will only enter integer values.

```
int main(){
    scanned = scanf(...); 
    while (scanned != 1 or the number scanned in was too small) { 
    // call scanf again.... 
    scanned = scanf(...); 
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

However when `scanf()` does not successfully read input from standard input that value remains in
standard input.  This means the call of `scanf()` inside the loop will keep trying to scan that same invalid input
over and over again (infinite loop!)

Comment: It's usually better to read in an entire line with e.g.: `fgets` into a buffer and then try to extract the values from that (with `sscanf` or similar)

Comment: like could you show me an example with the code? like im not quite sure...

Comment: Your wording had me confused for a second, and I think others here are still confused. In any case, which number is returned? The final number entered? Or the last minimum value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to completely clear stdin and the \n before scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772103/how-to-completely-clear-stdin-and-the-n-before-scanf)

Answer (score 1):

When working with unknown inputs it is usually preferable to read the input into a buffer and try to parse or extract data from that.

In your case it would probably make sense to look something like this:

```
int get_num(int min) {
  char buffer[1024]; // size arbitrarly chosen
  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
    // extract number
    int value;
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &value) != 1 || value < min) {
      // print some error message
      continue;
    }

    return value;
  }
  // return some "error value"
  return -1;
}
```